# Printing each iteration horizontally in different lines

Tags: python, printing

guys. I have a for loop and I managed to print the for loop horizontally

```
def triangular(number):
    for i in range (1, number+1):
        if number%i==0:
            print(number/i, end=" ")
```

This is what i get

```
15.0 5.0 3.0 1.0
```

However, if I try to use the function with different numbers, the code keeps printing it in the same line

```
triangular(1) 
triangular(3)

1.0 3.0 1.0 [Finished in 0.2s]
```

How can I do to print the results in a different line, every time I call the function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could print a return character `\n` after your loop like so:

```
def triangular(number):
    for i in range (1, number+1):
        if number%i==0:
            print(number/i, end=" ")
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a print at the end of the function

```
def triangular(number):
    for i in range (1, number+1):
        if number%i==0:
            print(number/i, end=" ")
    print("")
```